# Vulkan validation layers don't load/work on Linux

Tags: linux, vulkan

I have basic Vulkan application, "Hello triangle",derived from [this tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/). In debug mode I use two validations layers:

`VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` and  `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor`

On Windows I got no problem. Both layers load, I can see FPS counter in the title bar. But I am experiencing different behaviour on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

Only `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor` loads. No FPS counter appears in the title bar.

`VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` fails to load with the error:

> ERROR: libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

I performed Linux setup according to the guidelines appearing in this LunarG doc.

1. Put the whole LunarG SDK in an arbitrary location on my Linux
   filesystem.
2. Sourced `setup-env.sh` into `.profile` file
3. Inside the setup-env.sh script I also added `VK_LOADER_DEBUG=all` in order to see detailed info from Vulkan Loader.
4. Verified that all the variables set by the script point to correct directories in the SDK. They do.

setup-env.sh:

```
 VULKAN_SDK="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE:-$_}" )" )/x86_64"
 export VULKAN_SDK
 PATH="$VULKAN_SDK/bin:$PATH"
 export PATH
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$VULKAN_SDK/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 VK_LAYER_PATH="$VULKAN_SDK/etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d"
 export VK_LAYER_PATH
 export VK_LOADER_DEBUG=all
```

Here is the chunk I am gettin from debug output that show the failure of loading the layers:

> DEBUG: Loading layer library
>   /home/platform-thirdparty/vulkan-sdk/1.1.121.1/x86_64/lib/libVkLayer_monitor.so
>   INFO: Inserted device layer VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor
>   (/home/platform-thirdparty/vulkan-sdk/1.1.121.1/x86_64/lib/libVkLayer_monitor.so)
>   Message:libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory ERROR:
>   libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

Even though it says that

> Inserted device layer VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor

The monitor doesn't work.
If I replace `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` with `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` I am getting the same load fail error.
The debugger also shows that the loader did find all the manifest files for all the layers in the SDK.
I have no clue what else can be a problem.

My system setup:

Ubuntu 18.04 64bit, Nvidia RTX 3000
Nvidia Drivers: 430.0
VulkanSDK(LunarG): 1.1.121.1

Comment: What about 1.1.126? Monitor does not work on some platforms; I think e.g. wayland.

Comment: Well,didn't try yet the latest version. Hoped to track down this issue without upgrading.

Comment: @krOoze same thing with 1.1.126.0

Comment: Looks almost as if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is ignored. What happens if you edit the full path to the *.so in the json file?

Comment: Tried that one. Changed nothing.

Comment: Side note: The "monitor" layer is just a Vulkan Layer. The "Validation Layer(s)" is just the "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation" one

Comment: @FrickeFresh it doesn't matter in this context. This layer is still enabled  the same way as validation layers are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux) lies the answer by  user1824407.

It appears that in the latest Ubuntu distributions (at least in 18.04 I use) setting `LD_LIBRARY` path into config files like:
 `.profile`  or  `/etc/environment` or `.bashrc`

Doesn't take any effec.And indeed,I tried adding the lib path to all of those files, the libs didn't load even that `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` printed the pass I set.
And only when I added the path with the Vulkan validation layers location to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/devlibs.conf` where

> devlibs.conf

is an arbitrary name I gave the file,now I see both VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor and VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation are loaded by Vulkan.